# Getting exception when i try to copy data from Azure Blob to SQL Datawarehouse using DataFactory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have created a pipeline that uses the Copy activity to move data from Blob to SQL Datawarehouse.

```
Azure Blob Dataset:
"name": "TradeData",
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "HDInsightStorageLinkedService",
    "structure": [],
    "typeProperties": {
      "folderPath": "hdinsight/hive/warehouse/tradesummary/",
      "format": {
        "type": "OrcFormat"
      }
    },
SQL DW Dataset:
 "name": "TradeDataRepository",
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureSqlDWTable",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureSQLDataWarehouseLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
      "tableName": "tradesummary"
    },

Pipeline:
"activities": [
      {
        "name": "CopyActivityTemplate",
        "type": "Copy",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "TradeData"
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "TradeDataRepository"
          }
        ],
        "typeProperties": {
          "source": {
            "type": "BlobSource",
            "skipHeaderLineCount": 0
          },
          "sink": {
            "type": "SqlDWSink",
            "allowPolyBase": false
        }
```

When I execute the pipeline, i get following error:

> Database operation failed.
>   **Error message from database execution :**   ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error happened when loading data into SQL Data Warehouse.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: Exception:   Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Common.ExternalAccess.HdfsAccessException, Message: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_CreateRecordReader: Error [HdfsBridge::CreateRecordReader - Unexpected error encountered creating the record reader.] occurred while accessing external file [/hive/warehouse/tradesummary/000000_0][0].,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=110802,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=110802,State=1,Message=110802;An internal DMS error occurred that caused this operation to fail. Details: Exception:   Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Common.ExternalAccess.HdfsAccessException, Message: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_CreateRecordReader: Error [HdfsBridge::CreateRecordReader - Unexpected error encountered creating the record reader.] occurred while accessing external file [/hive/warehouse/tradesummary/000000_0][0].,},],'.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: This MSDN [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/91e6bb49-a812-4961-812c-dc277894a35d/internal-dms-error-occurred-that-caused-this-operation-to-fail?forum=sqldatawarehousing) lists a few reasons for same error, where the source data contains bit or uniqueidentifier.  It suggests the bit issue has been fixed but not the uniqueidentifier.  Can you confirm if your source data contains either of these datatypes?  The workaround is to cast to varchar for the guids.  Otherwise I would start with a simple file, one row, one column, build up from there.

Comment: No, we do not have columns with bit or unique identifer

Comment: Hi Madhu, Did you get any solution for your mentioned issue here

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the problem is with your sink (SQL Data warehouse), not with ADF. When there is inadequate system memory in the resource pool, this might be a temporary issue.

To double-check, try activating and disabling the "Skip incompatible rows" option in the ADF copy activity and doing a few test runs to see whether you're seeing the problem regularly.

As stated by [wBob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527504/wbob) as per the MSDN [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/91e6bb49-a812-4961-812c-dc277894a35d/internal-dms-error-occurred-that-caused-this-operation-to-fail?forum=sqldatawarehousing) there are other few reasons which could be when the source data includes a bit or a unique identification It appears that the bit problem has been resolved, but the unique identifier has not. Can you check that one of these datatypes exists in your source data. The GUIDs can be converted to varchar as a workaround.